# FirestoreRecyclerAdapter not importing

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I'm trying to add FirestoreRecyclerAdapter class but it doesn't work. I don't know why. This is the video that I followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLytVF2lMSQ  In 49.13, it is where it shows the import class of   import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;

The first one is where I'm trying to add the class 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0'. When I added "FirestoreRecyclerAdapter", an error showed up obviously, but there is no option that says "import class" unlike in the video.

The second code is the gradle. I added implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0' in the last line. I clicked on synchronize and there was no error.

Above firebase.auth class, I tried to add it, the but it would just show an error.

Can anyone try to help me to add FirestoreRecyclerAdapter class please?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;


import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link messageList#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class messageList extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    ImageView imageviewofuser;

    FirestoreRecyclerAdapter


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message_list, container, false);
    }
}
```

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*******"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.3'
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Try cleaning your project, then rebuild it. If that doesn't work, try Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Comment: What is the exact error that you get?

Comment: The error says "Cannot resolve symbol 'FirestoreRecyclerAdapter'". Unlike in the video there is no import class. The only option I can click is "Create type parameter FirestoreRecyclerAdapter".

Comment: Also I cleaned my project and rebuild it but it didn't work. So tried to invalidate Caches/Restart but nothing changed. Is there another way to solve it?

Comment: While I was rebuilding, an error showed that said "Could not find com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0." I was confused so I erased it, synchronized it then added again. However, it didn't work. So tried to invalidate Caches/Restart but nothing changed. Is there another way to solve it?*

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem so what you can do is first add these dependencies, it will work fine.

```
com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just import all the latest dependencies:
In my case it worked.

```
    dependencies {
    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.2'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.2'

    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:8.0.2'
}
```